# How can I test the proportion of "significant" effects in a logistic mixed effects model?

Tags: logistic, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I have a binary outcome variable $Y \in {0, 1}$ in $N$ groups that I assume to be generated by the logistic process
$$
P(y_{ij} = 1) = \frac{1}{1 + \text{exp}[-(\underline \beta_{j0} + \underline \beta_{j1}x_{ij1} + \underline \epsilon_{ij})]} \\
\underline \beta_{j0} = \beta_0 + \underline \delta_{j0} \\
\underline \beta_{j1} = \beta_1 + \underline \delta_{j1}
$$
, where

- $\beta_0$ is an intercept,
- $x_{ij1}$ is the only predictor variable and is **also binary** and on individual level
- $\beta_1$ is the true coefficient of the predictor variable
- $\underline \delta_{j0}$ and $\underline \delta_{j1}$ are random effects on group level,
- $\underline \epsilon_{ij}$ is a random effect on individual level,
- $j$ is the identifier on group level
- $i$ is the identifier on individual level

I haven't thought much about the distributions of $\underline \epsilon$ and $\delta$ but have so far stuck with a textbook assuming a logistic distribution for $\underline \epsilon$ and a normal distribution with mean 0 for $\underline \delta$.

**The Question:**

**How many (proportion) groups show a significant effect of $X$ on $Y$?**

Having a single group I would simply perform a $\chi^2$ test for independence with a four cell contingency table.  But doing that for every group and counting how many tests are above or below a certain $p$-value seems a bad procedure.

I could also summarize the success ratio of each group to a single value for each group and define a threshold value and count how many groups are above or below it.  But procedures like this do not take the multilevel structure into account, it seems to me.

How would you test for the proportion (e. g., "the proportion of 'significant' effects is higher than ...%") in such a scenario?  Would you even consider modelling the process as random coefficients, or take a different approach?

Example real-world scenarios I came across:

- Testing the effectiveness of displaying an ad banner on different shops (group level) in their web sessions (individual level) on purchase rate:  How many shops do benefit from it?
- Testing the effectiveness of protective clothing distributed to humans (individual level) in regions (group level) on infection infection rate: How many regions benefit from it?
- Testing the effectiveness of introducing laptops to students (individual) in classes (group level) on pass/fail rate: how many classes benefit from it?

To me this seems to be no uncommon case or question but so far I have failed to get the right ideas or keywords from books and the web.  If you think my assumption does not match the real world processes, please let me know.